# Hyperplanes, closedness and continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Given a normed vector space $V$, a function $f\colon V\to\mathbb R$ and a hyperplane $H = \{v \in V: f(v) = \alpha\}$ $(\alpha \in \mathbb R)$, how do you prove that if $H$ is closed, then $f$ must be continuous?
Please note that, by the definition of hyperplanes, $f$ has to be linear (which also means that $f(0)=0$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. please consider rewriting your post

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to prove this result, since the explanation I found on the Aliprantis textbook that I am looking at seems incorrect...

Comment: @user114618 I moved α outside the set (where it doesn't belong); but probably you should add that $f$ is linear. You can also add what you think incorrect, quoting the book.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$\;f\;$ is continuous iff $\;\ker f\;$ is closed, and the kernel of a non-zero linear functional is a hyperplane, so...

Comment: But that only proves that the hyperplane of the kernel is closed, NOT a generic hyperplane. Am I missing something?

Comment: Of course it does, @user114618: if $\;H\;$ is closed, then any translation $\;u+H\;$ is closed, and this last is a "general" hyperplane...

Comment: Just trying to clarify my thoughts. Don't leave! :)

Comment: According to wikipedia: a LINEAR functional is continuous iff its kernel is closed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_operator If I translate the function, this will not be linear any more, but simply affine (ie. it won't go through the origin any longer). The difference is subtle but it means that the result you mention cannot be used...

Answer (score 0):

$H\subset X$ is a hyperplane iff there is a linear function $f:X\to \Bbb R$, $f\neq 0$ and $t\in \Bbb R$ such that $H=f^{-1}(${$t$}$)$.

Then show what DonAntonio wrote.

Comment: Mitsos, thanks for the message. I think DonAntonio's answers does not prove the result. Do you know the answer to the question?